# User Agent for Salesforce1

Tags: mobile

We are using Salesforce1 mobile browser application and NOTthe salesforce1 app from apple/play store. The browser used is mobile iron Web@Work. Everything was fine till W@W 1.4 release but with ver 1.5 the Salesforce1 browser app started having some rendering issues. Eg. the list view on a tablet looked like the "phone" view / log a call looked like as if we are logging a call on a phone and similar examples.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated as to what could have caused the user agent change.

Web@Work 1.4.1 – Browser shows as “Chrome”.

Web@Work 1.5 – Browser shows as “Iron”.

Thanks, Laxmi[image]

Comment: OOTB behavior started working badly? Or code you've developed?

Comment: Out of box stuff working badly, eg, Salesforce has different way of showing list views on tablet and on phone. The tablet started showing list views as if they are on phone.

Comment: Does anyone know more about this issue?